# Ocultar o notice em PHP

Tags: php

O meu problema é o seguinte. Tenho as variáveis $qr1, $qr2 e $qr3, como podem ver no código abaixo, que só ficam válidas quando eu envio os dados via post. Mas preciso que elas fiquem ocultas para o usuário para não achar que deu erro quando ele entrar na página. Como posso fazer isso neste código?

```
<form class="recipiente coluna margem-topo-100" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="code" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Gerar QR Code" />
  <input type="hidden" name="gerar" value="s" />
</form>




  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['gerar'])) {



    require_once "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

    $valor = $_POST['code'];

    $code = $valor;

    QRcode::png($code, "Imagem_QRCODE_L.png", QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3);
    QRcode::png($code, "Imagem_QRCODE_M.png", QR_ECLEVEL_M, 5);
    QRcode::png($code, "Imagem_QRCODE_H.png", QR_ECLEVEL_H, 10);

    $qr1 = '<img src="Imagem_QRCODE_L.png"/>';
    $qr2 = '<img src="Imagem_QRCODE_M.png"/>';
    $qr3 = '<img src="Imagem_QRCODE_H.png"/>';

  }
  ?>

<section class="texto-centro margem-topo-50">
  <?=$qr1?>
  <?=$qr2?>
  <?=$qr3?>
</section>
```

Comment: pq não joga a `<section class="texto-centro margem-topo-50">` para dentro do if? precisa dessas variáveis separadas mesmo?

Comment: Não, como sou burro e não pensei nisso...rs Valeu @LINQ